# Practical deployments of ECC with cofactor of elliptic curves $4$ or $8$?

Tags: elliptic-curves, discrete-logarithm, dsa, cryptocurrency, elliptic-curve-generation

Are cofactor $4$ and $8$ ECC schemes widely used in practical deployments such as those in cryptocurrencies?

Can you name some practical settings where there curves are used and cryptocurrencies where these are used (I checked bitcoin and it uses cofactor $1$ ECC and so I was not sure if other cryptocurrencies also use cofactor $1$ ECC)?

Comment: Anything that uses curve25519 or ed25519, which have a cofactor of 8

Comment: @knaccc Any practical deployments of these?

Comment: There are many, it's very easy to google it. E.g. https://www.susanka.eu/coins-crypto/

Comment: @knaccc can you convert to an answer?

Comment: It would feel like I was just copy-pasting web pages into an answer. Two other links are https://ianix.com/pub/curve25519-deployment.html and https://ianix.com/pub/ed25519-deployment.html